# Understanding of foldLeft implementation

Tags: scala, fold

Hello!

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = 
           var result = z
           this foreach (x => result = op(result, x))
           result
```

Could you please explain - **this foreach (x =>**
how does it work? Why did not use **map**  ?

Answer (score 2):

> How does this work?

First, `this foreach (f)` can be de-sugared into `this.foreach(f)` (see **Arity-1** section [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)). Second, `foreach` expects a function with "side-effect" and a `Unit` return value. It applies that function once for every element, potentially updating some "state". In this case, notice the function body (right-hand side of the `=>` operator) **assigns** a new value to `var result`: it is updated on each iteration, where each iteration uses the value updated by the previous one (starting with the value `z`).

> Why not to use `map`?

`map` produces a new collection as a return value, which is simply not needed here - we're only interested in the "side-effect" of this anonymous function (i.e. updating `result`'s value) and not in any returned collection. If we used `map` with this same function, it would have resulted in a useless collection if `Unit`s...

Comment: I mean    `this foreach` == this

Answer (score 1):

`map` is used for iterating over all members of collection, apply some transformation and get back another / same collection.  While `foreach` is used for *side effect*.

Here we are applying  binary operator `op` on `result` and consecutive elements of collection (ie `x`), to get result of type `B` which is *not* necessarily a collection. That is why `map` is not used.

Comment: Note that map does not always result in things with the same size. Sets and Maps are two examples.

Comment: Agree with you. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

There's two answers: the first is what would happen if you literally just used `map` instead of `foreach` here, which is that the code would still work. You'd just be using something that's "too powerful" so to speak. You don't actually care about what the expression in the `foreach` returns, you only care about the side effect (the update to a `var`) that it does in each iteration.

`foreach` here functions the same way an imperative `for` loop does. To give an example from C, just as we don't write

```
// Nonsensical C
int x = for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x++;
}
```

and instead just write

```
// We don't assign the loop
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x++;
}
```

The second way to answer your question follows from a strong tradition within the Scala community *not to have side effects when performing a `map`* (or really any sort of traversal on a collection including folds). The exception to this rule is anything that returns `Unit` (e.g. `foreach`), because those expressions would otherwise be completely useless.

So with this tradition in mind why even have this side effect at all and not just use a `map`-based implementation.

Well we can't implement `foldLeft` in terms of map if we don't want it to have side effects, unless we have a very bizarre version of `map`. `map` in Scala acts on each element of a collection independently (for good reasons surrounding [parametricity](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/identifier-names/index.html)), while `foldLeft` must keep some sort of context (the accumulator) as it traverses a collection that it might use to influence what happens at each element of the collection. This independence of `map` on anything except the present element of a collection and the potential dependence that `foldLeft` allows on past values is fundamentally at odds; the latter is strictly more powerful (you can implement `map` in terms of `foldLeft`, see note).

This means in order to implement a fold, we have to use more powerful techniques to traverse the data structure. This boils down to two choices:

- recursion
- loops

The implementors chose the latter here instead of recursing.

Note: Depending on your definition of `map` there is a small bit of nuance here. If you want `map` to obey the functor laws, you can create a nonconforming `map` with a fold, but as long as a conformant version of `map` exists, then you can create it with a fold.